# Avoiding dog-piling or thundering herd in a memcached expiration scenario

Tags: django, algorithm, caching, memcached

I have the result of a query that is very expensive. It is the join of several tables and a map reduce job.

This is cached in `memcached` for 15 minutes. Once the cache expires the queries are obviously run and the cache warmed again.

But at the point of expiration the [`thundering herd problem`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem) issue can happen.

One way to fix this problem, that I do right now is to run a scheduled task that kicks in the 14th minute. But somehow this looks very sub optimal to me.

Another approach I like is nginx’s [`proxy_cache_use_stale   updating;`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache_use_stale) mechanism.

*The webserver/machine continues to deliver stale cache while a thread kicks in the moment expiration happens and updates the cache.*

Has someone applied this to `memcached` scenario though I understand this is a client side strategy?

If it benefits, I use **`Django`**.

Comment: I know you asked this 3 years ago. I'm curious, what did you end up using?

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at https://github.com/ericflo/django-newcache

Answer (score 1):

You want http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dogpile/ — it implements an algorithm exactly like `proxy_cache_use_stale updating`, and even works with memcachd.

Comment: Ah, sorry — it turns out that I've mislead you a bit. It turns out that the memcached backend is implemented in https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/dogpile.cache, but that's not quite production read yet.